# Joomla strange behaviour explanation needed (close button)

Tags: joomla1.5

I do apologize..I'm new to Joomla.
I'm refering to Joomla 1.5.17.

My scenario: Website Joomla based.I have access to the backend as Administrator. I need to modify 
an element (web content). After some rearrangement I erroneously close the application without resorting to the close button within the frame but just abruptly as in case of a sudden power failure.
A few days later, my collegue (same privileges as Admin) needs to get access to the same element but surprisingly she finds out that the same element is actually locked.

My question: is the application's behaviour described above correct? I mean, I believe it's quite odd
to be unable to get access to an application element (backend) given the fact that the application itself wad actually closed a few days earlier. Is Joomla the culprit?

I also have to point out the fact that only the one who first modified the element can later remove
the lock allowing anyone else to ge access to it.

Thanks in advance, any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the behavior is correct and it prevents two people from editing the same content at the same time.

The content is in "checked out" state. Only the person who checked out that content can check it in (and so unlock it) or a Super Administrator (may work with Administrator as well, but I did not test).

To do a bulk check in of articles that have been left checked out by mistake, go to the back end of the website. In the top menu go to: Tools > Global Check in. This will check in automatically any items where were checked out.

The important thing to realize here is that the check out/check in mechanism is there for your own protection. As I've said it prevent two ore more editors from editing the same pate at the same time.

So just make sure you check back in your edits and if some content is locked you may use the global check in feature to unlock it.

Best of luck!